# Библиотека glut в C. Меняю значение прозрачности, но ничего не происходит

Tags: c, glut

*Нужно нарисовать "воду" как синий полупрозрачный полигон, но изменение прозрачности в glColor4f() ничего не меняет. В initDisplayMode стоит GL_RGBA, не знаю, что еще может быть не так.*

```
**glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 100);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex2f(-1.2, -1.2);
glVertex2f(1.2, -1.2);
glVertex2f(1.2, 1.2);
glVertex2f(-1.2, 1.2);
glEnd();
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);**
```

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Transparency